# How edit enable cipher suites in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: encryption, internet-explorer-11

I want to edit the configuration of cipher suites in IE11, but I don't find any explication about how to change it.

My goal is to delete the cipher suites that [this web](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html) say that it is weak

My expected is that my browser don't support this cipher suites.

I have tried `gpedit.msc` but doesn't work in Windows 10 Home.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better recommendation would be to stop using internet explorer 11 completely. In windows 10 you can now uninstall IE from the features panel in windows.

You can configure the cipher suites from an Administrative powershell commandline as well:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/tls/index?view=win10-ps

`Disable-TlsCipherSuite`
Disables a TLS cipher suite.

`Disable-TlsEccCurve` 
Disables TLS Ecc Curve.

`Enable-TlsCipherSuite` 
Enables a TLS cipher suite.

`Enable-TlsEccCurve` 
Enables TLS Ecc Curve.